# Command+join anchor points from different groups? Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I have two anchor points I want to join to form a rectangle but they are both part of two different groups (it is a reflected group flipped horizontally).
I get an error message when I try command +J.
[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I think the error message is pretty clear. Try ungrouping the groups before attempting to join the two anchors.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I ungrouped them both but still comes up with error message could there be another reason?

Comment: There might be several groups within groups. Keep ungrouping until there are no groups left - i.e. until ungroup is greyed out

Comment: Another way to be sure the paths are not grouped is: Select both paths, cut and paste. Now both paths are not grouped with any group.